# Virtually move Host to foreign Network

Tags: networking, subnet

is there a way to move a host virtually to a different network based on its mac-address?
Example: Imagine a firewall with a LAN (let's say 192.168.1.0/24) and a DMZ (e.g. 172.1.1.0/24) interface.
Assume there is a host that can only be connected to the DMZ-network due to the physical wiring in the building but is supposed to be in the LAN-subnet (and have LAN-security policies applied to it).
Something similar to a VLAN on the DMZ without a seperate subnet, but the host in question seamlessly integrated into the foreign (here: LAN-network)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. It is handled by the switch, which assigns the proper VLAN depending on the MAC address. You need to have all VLANs configured on the switches that are involved. How this is configured depends on the hardware you are using, so you need to check the documentation of your switches.

Note that this really more for convenience, since MAC addresses can be easily spoofed.

If you want to properly and securely assign devices to VLANs take a look at 802.1x, which uses client certificates to assign VLANs. It is of course more complex to set up.